# Lost the content in localhost:4200 while working in Angular

Tags: angular

My app.module.ts file asked for compare or overwrite while saving.Mistakenly I have overwritten the app.module.ts file. And hence I lost the outcome in localhost:4200. How can I get the things back?

Comment: Usually people use version control systems like git for this purpose.

Comment: If you are under any version control system then check the difference and use it. If not then fix the code by your own. You can share the code and expected behavior to get help from here.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an Angular project, a Git repository is initialized.
Git is a version control system, a system that stores snapshots of your files when you make modifications on them called *commits* in order to return to a previous state if you have a problem.

Some IDEs like WebStorm track changes made to files in order to rollback to a previous state, but it doesn't replace a version control system.